# How can I chart based on day and month using dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a Google spreadsheet that has values like:

```
1/1/10 0
1/2/10 43
1/3/10 17
etc.
```

I want to be able to visualize the data on a day-by-day basis and on a month by month basis.

I managed to create a chart based on the day - but I can't figure out how to automatically group the months.

What can I do?

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56780/how-can-i-group-a-pivot-table-into-weeks-or-months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you're looking for is something like Pivot Tables of Excel, where you can [group](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/pivot-table-group-dates-by-month.php) by anything you want.

Unfortunately there is no such support in Google Spreadsheet. What you (or someone) could do though is to write a simple script to group them for you. If you're interested you can start with some [tutorials](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/articles.html).

Comment: Yes - this is the exact feature I was looking for. I did not know the name of it though.   I already know how to code for google docs - but I was hoping I would not have to resort to it for a task such as this :-(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest (a) a formula to extract the month (might need year too, depending on the timespan), say `=month(a2)` copied down to suit (b) a pivot table to aggregate (`Month` in **Rows** and `Value` in **Values** as Summarize by: SUM) and then (c) chart that:

[image: WA8400 example]

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017, Google Sheets [now supports pivot tables](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120852/48470) for details.