# How to make time series chart, where all rows are labelled and dates are not unique?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Say I have some data like so

```
| Month | Count | Type |    |    |
|-------|-------|------|--- |--- |
|     1 |     2 | A    |    |    |
|     1 |     3 | B    |    |    |
|     2 |     1 | A    |    |    |
|     2 |     2 | B    |    |    |
|     3 |     1 | A    |    |    |
|     3 |     1 | B    |    |    |​
```

I would like to create a line chart, which each Type would have its own line.

In data studio this behaviour is set by default, but is there an easy way to do it with google sheets?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/8400/88163

Answer (score 1):

See [Test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aepvuNfWBMVO6oHJXNMo1zmISsKj33pN_3qxClrcYdU/edit#gid=0)

Idea is to make pivot table to group your data by type and month and create chart based on pivot table.
Since data may be updated, increase range of pivot table and filter blanks.

Comment: **Amazing!!!** I am new to google sheets so was unaware of pivot tables